# Could not find a declaration file for module "joi-objectid"

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I tried `npm install @types/joi-object` and it just gives me a **code E404** and **'@types/joi-objectid@3.0.1' is not in the npm registry.**.

I can't progress with the course I'm taking cause I'm kinda new in NodeJs.

Any suggestions?